# How to write in Markdown for VSC a code string regular expression like [a-z](bar)

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, markdown

In the `README.md` file of my extension I need to write a regular expression that contains a character set `[]` followed by a capturing group `()`. In Markdown this is the syntax for a link.

The VSC Markdown preview shows this as a link if I don't put it in backticks. Surrounded with backticks it looks good in the Markdown preview and on [github (Example 2)](https://github.com/rioj7/html-related-links/blob/master/README.md).

The page in the [VisualStudio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) adds the repository URL, so does the extension page inside VSC.

How do I modify

```
* `[\\/](?=[^\\/]+$).*bar`
```

to make VSC not recognize it as a URL?

Comment: is this solved? adding text within \`\`\`text \`\`\` works

Comment: @Morse I have it with single and triple back tick and it was still not solved some time ago for a different extension, I have added an issue for this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103846